# How to achieve this simple and elegant spinner layout?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-spinner

I found this image from the google dev page and the spinner looks great.

[image]

I wanted to know how we can get this design/layout for the spinner view in android. Can someone please detail this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [**`TextInputLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) in the Material Components Library with a `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu` style:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:hint="Hint Text">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]